# Conectar con SSH a instancia de AWS

Tags: linux

Tengo una instancia de Ubuntu creada en AWS, he generado el `.pem` para conectarme con SSH de la siguiente manera:
ssh -i mi_key.pem usuario@ip

Mi sorpresa es que he podido conectarme desde el terminal de mi Mac la primera vez pero si quiero volver a conectarme me dice lo siguiente:

`ssh -i mi_key.pem usuario@ip`

`@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
9f:24:59:52:38:78:de:9f:bb:f1:e0:69:3e:b1:5b:af.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/sergio/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/sergio/.ssh/known_hosts:31
RSA host key for "ip" has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.`

Comment: Deberías especificar un poco más el tema, he llegado a la pregunta a través de la cola de votos de cierre porque la pregunta no está muy clara. Supongo que lo que quieres es "¿por qué pasa esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?", podrías añadir información información adicional como si estás conectándote desde equipos diferentes o si tienes múltiples conexiones al mismo tiempo.

Comment: La pregunta no esta clara, pero el problema es clarisimo para el que sabe de que se esta hablando. A veces creo que somos mas papistas que el papa. En su respuesta, esta la solucion, y es un problema muy comun, al menos entre mis cientos de clientes, cuando son novatos con SSH.

Answer (score 3):

Disculpad, ya lo he solucionado:

El fichero donde se guardan claves en el equipo local es /home/usuario/.ssh/known_hosts.
Según indica el mensaje de error, en este caso se trata de la primera clave guardada:

Offending key in /home/usuario/.ssh/known_hosts:1

Se puede editar este fichero y eliminar esa clave pero más sencillo es utilizar la orden ssh-keygen con la opción -R

usuario@sorse:~$ ssh-keygen -R equipo.remoto.es:7654

Si se utilizase el puerto estándar ssh bastaría con indicar el nombre del equipo remoto después de la opción -R.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, para clarificar el problema.